# Django Database Error due to Unicode characters

Tags: python, django, unicode

I don't know why am I still getting this error:

```
DatabaseError: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xF0\\xA0\\x83\\x8F\\xF0\\xA0...' for column
```

Most of the filenames in unicode characters where already properly saved on the DB-table and I've already used unicode literals to save them, like this:

```
Submission(id=id, filename=u'<actual filename>').save()
```

But as mentioned, this approach doesn't work for all unicode characters.
How will I handle this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the "actual filename" that you are feeding in? Is it written in Cyrillic or Arabian script, by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

try using smart_str

```
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str
...
Submission(id=id, filename=smart_str('<actual filename>')).save()
```